# having a problem with code in flex(part in C)

Tags: c

When I compile a C file, it says:

```
pcat.lex:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘hasTab’.
```

Here's the beginning of the file:

```
#include "ctype.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "pcat.tab.h"
#define YY_USER_ACTION Do_Before_Each_Action();
#define STRING_MAX_LENGTH 255
#define IDENTIFIER_MAX_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_INT 2147483647
static int lineno = 1;
static int colno = 1;
static bool hasTab;
void Do_Before_Each_Action();
```

Does anybody know what happens?
I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bool` is not C. Try `int` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`bool` is not a pre-C99 keyword.  (In fact, it's still only a macro in C99.)

Answer (score 1):

`bool` is not a recognized as a keyword in C.

You can either try using `g++` to compile as C++, or try defining bool as `int`, along with constants for `true` and `false`.  For instance:

```
typedef int bool;
const bool  true = 1;
const bool false = 0;

bool a;

int main()
{
  bool a = true;
}
```

Compilation works fine:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ # no errors
```